# Type constraint on input function parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I'm trying to create a higher order function that has an upper bound on the type of the parameter accepted by the input function.

A toy example of a naive attempt that demonstrates the problem:

```
class A
class B extends A

def AFunc(f: A => Unit): Unit = {}

AFunc((b: B) => {})

//<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
// found   : B => Unit
// required: A => Unit
//       AFunc((b: B) => {})
```

This doesn't work, I assume, because functions are contravariant in their parameters so B => Unit is a supertype of A => Unit.

It's possible to get it working with polymorphic functions like so:

```
class A
class B extends A

def AFunc[T <: A](f: T => Unit): Unit = {}

AFunc[B]((b: B) => {})
```

This solution has the drawback of requiring the caller to know the exact type of the passed function's parameter, despite the fact that all AFunc cares about the type is that it is a subtype of A.

Is there a type-safe way to enforce the type constraint without explicitly passing the type?

Comment: Well, you can't not know the type of the parameter, because you are _passing it in_ :) Perhaps, you meant having to spell out the type explicitly at call site, but you don't actually need to do that, just `AFunc((b: B) => {})` will work.

Comment: Oh wow, that does work! I feel a bit silly. Growing pains of learning a new language, I suppose.

Comment: @Dima It doesn't seem as though the bounds are enforced without explicitly specifying the type? For instance, AFunc((b: Int) => {}) doesn't throw an error, but AFunc[Int]((b: Int) => {}) does.

Comment: Hm ... yeah, seems like a bug :/ But I played around with it a little bit to see how bad it can actually get, a discovered, that I don't really know what you can _do_ with this function: there is no (good/typesafe) way to invoke `f` inside of `AFunc` (you can't get the argument of the right type), so ...

Comment: Ok, not a bug :) It looks like `AFunc((b: Int) => {})` compiles because `T` is inferred as `A with Int` ... it's a funny type, of course, of which you can never create an actual instance, but then again, that applies to this entire function in general: there is no way to obtain an actual instance of `T` inside of it, regardless of what the actual `T` is.

Comment: That seems odd to me, but I'm guessing it's in part due to it being a bad idea to begin with as you're indicating. I suspect as I read more typelevel docs I'll come across a standard way to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is not due to language construct limitations, it's conceptual. There is a reason why functions are contravariant in their arguments.

What would you expect to happen if we take your code and extend it slightly into a following situation:

```
class A
class B extends A

def AFunc(f: A => Unit): Unit = {
  f(new A) // let's use the function f
}

AFunc((b: B) => {}) // ???
```

How would this compile? Method `AFunc` clearly needs a way to handle values of type `A`, but you only provided it with a way of handling one subset of those values (= those of type `B`).

Sure, you can make your method polymorphic the way you did, and btw you won't even need to specify the argument type at call-site because it will be inferred. BUT, this is not the "solution". It's simply a different thing. Now instead of saying "I need a function that handles values of type `A`", your method is saying "I need a function that handles one particular subtype of `A`, but I will be fine with whatever subtype you decide on".

So, as it often happens on StackOverflow, I have to ask you - what are you trying to achieve? Is your method `AFunc` going to be handling all kinds of `A`s, or just one particular subtype at a time?

If it's the latter, parameterising with an upper bound (as you did) should be fine. Just be careful with the inference if you decide not to specify the type at call site, because sometimes your code might compile just because the compiler inferred something other than what you intended (I see from the comments in your question that you already discovered this behaviour). But, if parametric method is indeed what you need, then I don't see why would specifying the type at call-site be a problem.

> despite the fact that all AFunc cares about the type is that it is a subtype of A.

Sure, `AFunc` doesn't care. But the caller does. I mean, someone must care, right? :) Again, it's hard to continue discussion without knowing more about the actual problem you're solving, but if you want to provide more details I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for elucidating this more. I understand now why my construction wouldn't be useful, though it's still unclear to me why the type inference on the polymorphic function would be so lenient. I ran into this problem when doing some very basic prototyping for an embedded DSL. As I mentioned in the comments to my original post, I still have a lot of reading to do which I'm sure will give me a better direction and would probably be more fruitful than trying to troubleshoot this specific implementation.